# How to get count of unique IP addresses and errors in shell scripting using uniq or awk?

Tags: awk, uniq, nslookup

I am doing a nslookup on URLs for multiple iterations using shell script. I need to check how many times IP was returned for each URL.

In output file, output is stored as

```
URL 
IP address
```

using uniq -c command I get the count when same IP addresses are adjacent but not when same IP addresses are on non-adjacent line

```
Command is 
cat file.log | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c
```

here is the sample output

```
1 url
3 72.51.46.230
```

Now if multiple IP addresses are returned for a particular URL and they are on non-adjacent lines because I have run no. of iterations. In that case uniq-c command will not work. If I use sort option it sorts but I need to display the output as above for each URL ie. URL and next line with the count and its IP address.

For eg. if I do nslookup on google.com it will return multiple addresses and I do uniq -c I get following output. As you see there are same IP addresses but count is only 1 as uniq -c does not work on non-adjacent lines.

```
  1 74.125.236.64
  1 74.125.236.78
  1 74.125.236.67
  1 74.125.236.72
  1 74.125.236.65
  1 74.125.236.73
  1 74.125.236.70
  1 74.125.236.66
  1 74.125.236.68
  1 74.125.236.71
  1 74.125.236.69
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
  1 74.125.236.70
  1 74.125.236.66
  1 74.125.236.68
  1 74.125.236.71
  1 74.125.236.69
```

I tried with AWK as well but in that case output is not formatted as I require.

Awk command

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a) printf "%-2d -> %s \n", a[i], i}' file.log
```

Can you suggest a better solution to achieve this -
 Get count and Display in the format as mentioned above?

Output format desired is

```
URL
Count IP address
```

sample input file.

```
URL1
72.51.46.230
72.51.46.230
google.com
74.125.236.64
74.125.236.78
(null)
nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
```

Sample Output required as

```
URL1
2 72.51.46.230
google.com
1 74.125.236.64
1 74.125.236.78
1 null
5 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
```

Thank you.

Comment: can different domain/url point to same ip-address in your file? you better give a sample input...

Comment: Please provide a representative sample input file.

Comment: How should `(null)` be handled? Skipped over an all IP's count for `google` after `google.com`?

Comment: Null can be avoided. Do not care about null.

Comment: In above case instead of null, if an error is returned say nslookup:can't resolv url, how do I handle that and take error count also in output?

Comment: As a general comment, if you changed the input file format to line-oriented (e.g. tab-delimited; `google.com (tab) 12.34.56.78`) the rest would follow easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `awk` script does the job:

```
$1~/[a-z]+[.].*/{         # If line have a letter in must be a URL 
    for(i in ip)          # Print all the counts and IPs (empty first time)
         print ip[i],i      
    delete ip             # Delete array for next set of IP's
    print                 # Print the URL 
    next                  # Skip to next line
}
{
    ip[$0]++              # If here line contains IP, increment the count per IP 
}
END{                      # Reached end of file need to print the last set of IPs
    for(i in ip)
        print ip[i],i
}
```

Save it as `script.awk` and run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
creativecommons.org
2 72.51.46.230
google.com
5 nslookup: can't resolv 'google.com'
1 (null)
1 74.125.236.64
1 74.125.236.78
```

Comment: thank you. this worked perfect. Can you let me know what next and [a-z] does?

Comment: @sudo-o   can you help me with taking errors also into account in output? As show above in place of null if an error is returned say 'nslookup: can't resolv url  how do I take that also and print error count below the url

Comment: @sudo-o I have modified the output file above where you can see errors.

Comment: I used following command `awk '/[a-z]/{for(i in a) print a[i],i; delete a;print; next}{a
[$0]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}' file.log`  but in this case IP count is fine only count for errors is not shown. It just prints errors same as it is

Comment: If you have a new question then post a new question, make sure to explain you problem clearly, give an example input and the expected example output.

Comment: @sudo-o  I have provided sample input and output file above. Question is same about getting count but now requiring to include errors.

Comment: @sudo-o I modified the question as well to include that errors are also needed to take into account.

Comment: @user2074894 okay, okay, I have updated the scripts, modification is simple, just add block to deal with the errors.

Comment: @sudo-o Thank you. I will give this a try. One more thing how do i print stderr nslookup: can't resolv in same file as where IPs are recorded. I tried 2> at end of loop in main while loop but that overwrites other outputs.

Comment: @sudo-o The script which you gave works but it prints errors and its count at the end of file. It does not print error after the URL for which error was received.

Comment: @sudo-o I meant from above that error and its count is not printed after the URL for which error was received.

Comment: Post a clear question **from the start**. Do **not** change the requirements of question multiple times. Trying understanding the code I wrote, It's clearly commented and the modification are simple to keep the error under the following URL. I will **not** be making any changes to this answers now.

Answer (score 0):

Try your first command but add `sort`:

```
awk '{print $1}' file.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: @Kent, different URL will not point to same IP-address. As I am running same no. of iterations on each URL, i get same IP for that URL.

Comment: I have tried sort it does work but it also sorts the URL names so I cannot display the output in format as I desire. In above if you see for URL creativecommons.org, I ran 3 iterations and I get the count.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' file.log
```

instead of multiple commands and piping each command's output.

If you want it without awk:

`cut -f1 -d"\t" file.log|sort|uniq-c` will do